# Why ItemTouchHelper.Callback's onChildDraw will be called after clearView

Tags: android

The thing is I'd like to perform an elevation on the item while it's being dragged in RecyclerView.

Based on what the documentation says, I am supposed to customize my dragged view's behaviors in [ItemTouchHelper.Callback#onChildDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#onChildDraw(android.graphics.Canvas,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20boolean)) because it says

> If you would like to customize how your View's respond to user interactions, this is a good place to override.

Then I should clear my customizations in [ItemTouchHelper.Callback#clearView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#clearView(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder)) because it says

> Called by the ItemTouchHelper when the user interaction with an element is over and it also completed its animation.

**But the problem is `onChildDraw` will always be called one more time after `clearView`.**

So even if I cleared the customized behaviors in `clearView`, still it will be re-called in `onChildDraw`. Then what's the purpose of `clearView`?

Here is my code:

```
class MyItemTouchCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        // Set elevation for dragged itemView
        ViewCompat.setElevation(viewHolder.itemView, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_elevation));
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        // Clear elevation for dragged itemView
        ViewCompat.setElevation(viewHolder.itemView, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you release your finger, the `isCurrentlyActive` value becomes _false_. The `onChildDraw()` will still be called, but you don't need to set elevation anymore. Also, do not load your dimension resource in `onChildDraw()` every time - do it once in the constructor and save to a field.

Answer (score 3):

Of course we can solve this problem with a trick, it's easy to understand. Remember with a boolean variable `viewBeingCleared` when the dragged itemView is being cleared, then we can decide to call customized code in `onChildDraw` or not.

However this is not the best solution. We'd better **know why** and then we will **know how**, isn't it?

Trick solution:

```
class MyItemTouchCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    boolean viewBeingCleared;

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                            float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        if (viewBeingCleared) {
            viewBeingCleared = false;
        } else {
            ViewCompat.setElevation(viewHolder.itemView, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.common_elevation));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        ViewCompat.setElevation(viewHolder.itemView, 0);
        viewBeingCleared = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check `if (isCurrentlyActive)`